# Error in Map() in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, redux, depth-first-search

I am trying to implement DFS algorithm in React, Redux to visualize it.
To create a Adjacency List I am using the `Map()` data structure in JavaScript:

```js
dfs(v, visited, adjList) {
  console.log(v);
  visited[v] = true;

  var get_neighbours = adjList.get(v);

  for (var i in get_neighbours) {
    var get_elem = get_neighbours[i];
    if (!visited[get_elem])
      this.dfs(get_elem, visited, adjList);
  }
}

dfsStart(e) {
  var n = 0;
  var adjList = new Map();
  for (var i = 0; i < this.props.edges.length; i++) {
    n = Math.max(this.props.edges[i].u, this.props.edges[i].v);
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    adjList.set(i, []);
  }
  for (var key of adjList.keys()) {
    console.log(key);
  }
  //console.log(adjList.size);
  for (var i = 0; i < this.props.edges.length; i++) {
    var x = this.props.edges[i].u;
    var y = this.props.edges[i].v;
    console.log(x + " " + y);
    [...adjList.get(x), y] - > where I am getting error
  }
  for (var key of adjList.values()) {
    console.log(key);
  }
  var visited = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    visited[i] = false;
  }
  this.dfs(1, visited, adjList);
}
```

I even tried to push values into the empty list using the `push()` method as follows

```
adjList.get(x).push(y)
```

But this gives me an error too!

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>       at Function.from ()

And when I use `push()`:

> Layout.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `push` of undefined
>       at Layout.dfsStart (Layout.js:72)

Comment: What error? That's rather important information.

Comment: @Carcigenicate updated ! including the error statement

Comment: I don't see a `from()` call in your provided code, please point out what line of code that error is pointing to. As for the second error that is telling you that `get(x)` didn't return a value if that error is referring to `adjList.get(x).push(y)`

Comment: @GaganGanapathy For the second error at least, that means that `adjList.get(x)` is returning undefined.

Comment: It should not return undefined right It’s and empty list initially

Comment: @PatrickEvans get(x) should return an empty list initally into which im pushing values .. I don't why its  saying 'undefined'

Comment: [If the passed key cannot be found `get()` will return `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get#Return_value). Log `x` to make sure it is what you think it is

Comment: @PatrickEvans I tired printing the keys() they log prefectly also values of x log perfectly , they are the same as the ones I input , only when I use the get(x) method it fails

Comment: @PatrickEvans could you please look into the answer I posted , I have resolved the error I was getting but getting another error now

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to take the maximum x value into `n` instead of the last x or y, change:

```
for(var i=0;i<this.props.edges.length;i++)
  n = Math.max(this.props.edges[i].u, this.props.edges[i].v);
```

To:

```
n = Math.max(...this.props.edges.map(edge => edge.u));
```

Comment: I need the max value that x or y attains which will give the total number of vertices in the graph

Comment: @gagan yes but as you only set `n` arrays into the Map, you should make sure that `n` is actually bigger than `x`  which ut isnt in your code, causing all the trouble.

Comment: n = Math.max(n, Math.max(this.props.edges[i].u, this.props.edges[i].v)); what if use this ... this seems correct but doesn't work

Comment: I tried what you asked me to do, but I am still getting the error I mentioned above... there's a problem with pushing elements in to the empty list which i have set using the .set() function

Comment: I am referring to this website [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-graph-javascript/]

Answer (score 0):

```
dfs(v, visited, adjList) {
console.log(v);
visited[v] = true;

var get_neighbours = adjList.get(v);

console.log(get_neighbours);

for (var i in get_neighbours) {
    var get_elem = get_neighbours[i];
    //console.log(get_elem);
    if (!visited[get_elem]) {
        this.dfs(get_elem, visited, adjList);
    }
 }
}



dfsStart(e) {
var n = 0;
var adjList = new Map();
for(var i=0;i<this.props.edges.length;i++) {
  n = Math.max(n, Math.max(this.props.edges[i].u, this.props.edges[i].v));
  adjList.set(this.props.edges[i].u, []);
}
for(var i=0;i<this.props.edges.length;i++) {
  adjList.get(this.props.edges[i].u).push(this.props.edges[i].v);
}
var visited = [];
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
  visited[i] = false;
}
this.dfs(1, visited, adjList);
}
```

Doing this solves the problem, but still gives an undefined error in the dfs() function when i console.log(get_neighbours),